# NCReplaceRepeated destroys noncommutativity; is this a bug?

Tags: replacement, ncalgebra

I am pretty new to patterns in Mathematica.  Here is the example I want to consider:

```
<<NC`
<<NCAlgebra`
SetNonCommutative[a, b, c, d, e]

ReplaceRepeated[a ** b ** c ** d ** e, {X___**c**d**Y___ -> X**Y}]
```

That is, I want to remove `c**d` from the multiplcation chain. However, the output I am getting is

```
a b e
```

That is, the multiplication is now commutative. That is clearly not correct. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is replacement with ** is trick. See section *ReplaceAll (/.) and ReplaceRepeated (//.) often fail* of the manual. The best fix is to use the `NCReplace` family of functions. But you still need to be carefull.

In your case there is a lot going on here for it to fail. Let me start with a couple of alternatives.

1. `NCReplaceAll[a ** b ** c ** d ** e, c ** d -> Sequence[]]`

is the simplest way to do it that I can think of. A pattern like yours would also work if you make the rule delayed, as in

2. `NCReplaceAll[ a ** b ** c ** d ** e, {X___ ** c ** d ** Y___ :> X ** Y}]`

This works because the right-hand side of the rule is only evaluated after the match, at which time `X` and `Y` hold noncommutative symbols and the `**` survives the evaluation. The reason why your rule is failing is because the right-hand side, that is `X ** Y` is evaluated *before* the match is done. At that time, `X` and `Y` are the global `X` and `Y` which are, in the absence of a `SetNonCommutative` command, commutative. Therefore `X ** Y` evaluates to `X Y` *before* the rule is even applied. To make it even more confusing, the rule

3. `NCReplaceAll[ a ** b ** c ** d ** e, {x___ ** c ** d ** y___ -> x ** y}]`

would have worked because `x` and `y` are set as noncommutative by default so that the right-hand side evaluates to `x**y` even if you use `->` instead of `:>`.